# How to Get Out of Time Share

Tags: scams, law, timeshare

One of my friend bought a time share (in the Las Vegas of Midwest) about 5 years ago. He has barely used it since then. And recently he had some hard time with some financial troubles and death in the family.

Last week, he went to the timeshare company to somehow get rid of the Timeshare. To his utter surprise, they were least sympathetic about his situation and told him that he cannot get out of the timeshare "according to the terms and conditions", and if he doesn't act, it would be pass on to his children and would be burden on them.

The marketing guy asked him to update to new terms and conditions by buying another timeshare property and he would be able to get out of it in 10 years according to the new policies. (This of course will cost him about $9K)

I am sure there is a way out then just keep feeding to these scammers.

Can someone suggest how can he get out of this Timeshare contract, without wasting more money.

Plz help.

Comment: you can typically sell/transfer ownership of a timeshare to some other poor soul that thinks it's a good idea to buy one. the timeshare company usually doesn't care who they are getting money from, as long as they are getting money.

Comment: This will depend very much on the terms and conditions. The part about being a burden on the children is likely total bunk, though - parties owed money can get paid from the estate of a deceased person before heirs do, but debts generally do not transfer to the next of kin unless they're a co-signer (some exceptions apply).

Comment: There are companies which specialize in breaking TS leases.  I don't know how expensive/difficult it is, though.

Comment: "if he doesn't act, it would be pass on to his children and would be burden on them" They're lying. https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/finance/inheriting-timeshares

Comment: @rhavelka, well, you don't wish that to happen to other "poor soul". My friend is considering hiring a lawyer that specializes in this kind of cases. I even read online, that you just stop paying the yearly dues, they may threaten to impact your credit score, but if you do it 1-2 times, they may let you off the hook.

Comment: Did he read the terms and conditions when he signed up? Was he aware that nobody who owns a timeshare likes it?